Cannot Find Singing Tab In Visual Studio Project Properties
I am trying to sign project assemblies using a .pfx certificate file. But I cannot find the Signing Tab in Visual Studio Project Properties
My Solution has many projects and none of them shows the signing tab. Checked both Console Application and Class Library Projects as well.
Visual Studio Community Version: 17.10.3
.NET Framework : 8.0


Based on my testing, the Signing tab is available when using .NET Framework 3.0 and 4.8. However, it is not present when using .NET 8.0.
This means that older versions support the method you mentioned for signing assemblies, while the newer version requires referring to the documentation below for signing.
How to: Sign an assembly with a strong name
For example:
Open Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt or Visual Studio Developer PowerShell, and enter the following command:
al /out:<assemblyName> <moduleName> /keyfile:<keyfileName>

Where:
• assemblyName is the name of the strongly signed assembly (a .dll or .exe file) that Assembly Linker will emit.
• moduleName is the name of a .NET Framework code module (a .netmodule file) that includes one or more types. You can create a .netmodule file by compiling your code with the /target:module switch in C# or Visual Basic.
• keyfileName is the name of the container or file that contains the key pair. Assembly Linker interprets a relative path in relation to the current directory.


Does that mean I will not be able to sign assemblies using a .pfx certificate and that too after code Build? I do have a bat script which sign all required assemblies using signtool.exe but that's an additional step to be done after code building which I am trying to avoid. Insights on this will be helpful. thanks

You're using .NET 8. The Signing tab and Security Tab has moved. It's now under the Publish option from the drop down Build. See this video. I show you how to create a free PFX file: https://youtu.be/X3bM5GBAMvI
